# Sinus taylor series in C

Tags: c, trigonometry, taylor-series

Hello i have an assignemt where i have to create a function that calculates the sin value for a given x value using taylor series. I have written the following code, and it seems the problem occurs in the part for factorial, but im not sure?

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>


double x;
int n;
double fact = 3;
double sum = 0;
double factsum = 1;


int factf(double fact)
{
    
    for (int i = 1; i < fact; i++)
    {
        factsum = factsum * i;
    }
}
double taylor_sine(double x, int n)
{
    x = (x*3.14)/180;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + (pow(x, fact)/factf(fact));
        fact = fact + 2;
        factsum = 1;
    }
    sum = x - sum;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the value for x\n");
    scanf("%lf", &x);
    printf("Enter the number of precision\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    taylor_sine(x, n);
    
    printf("Sum = %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Comment: None of the functions, which are not `void`, return any value!

Comment: At least use a decent value for for pi.

Comment: `factf` returns an `int` (or at least it's declared to return an `int`). It should return a `double`.

Comment: Good catch. Function `factf()` is maintaining a global product, but that's ignored by the caller. That is horrible practice, as is setting a variable for next use, instead of setting it before use. The `factf()` function should explicitly begin with `1` anyway, not rely on that being done elsewhere. "Spaghetti" code.

Comment: [PI Day Million Digits](https://www.piday.org/million/) is helpful. You can even gather enough to support 128-bit `double` computations. A helpful example of [Taylor Series sine/cosine](https://paste.opensuse.org/71143720)

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code, the most critical ones are:

Your factorial function calculates the factorial of (n - 1).

It does not return the calculated value (`return factsum;`).

You are treating the alternating sign wrongly. You have to change the sign in each iteration.

As others have pointed out already, you should really use return values of functions instead of writing to global variables.

You use the float "precision" parameter as the maximum number of Taylor terms.

With those fixed, the calculation works (although inefficiently and with poor accuracy).

Comment: To clarify a bit further the assignment given states i have to use a x input for the angle in degrees and n for the precision. I know the accuracy of the taylor series is very bad, however this is to learn how to make a libary for use later.

I have tried updating the code but still no luck

Comment: Update added in original post

Comment: For small angles, the Taylor series is not so bad. For improved accuracy, you should use a better approximation of π. Please note also that you cannot calculate too many series terms as the factorial will very soon leave the range of `int`.

Comment: Sorry im still new to using Stackoverflow and programming :) I think i figured it out, and the problem is the accuracy of what i expected vs what it returned, and i changed the factorial to a double, and the precision of pi which gave a little better result.

Thanks for the help :)